# django-rest-auth Custom Serializer or custom Model

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

**Django Rest Framework**

how can i configure rest-auth to work with custom Serializer or custom model that takes in a name field instead of the default username.

Comment: Have you look here, [Django rest auth Configuration](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)?

Comment: Yah, but it doesn't really gives a use case example.. Am new to django rest framework